# How to identify performance issue based on Redis SLOWLOG

Tags: redis

My application encountered performance issue and I found it sometimes took 1+ minute to perform 2 redis `SMEMBERS` commands. When I checked `SLOWLOG GET` I found 100+ entries, some of them took over 20 seconds to perform.

The problem is, in the `SLOWLOG` vary commands were recorded, such as `KEYS`, `SREM`, `LPUSH` and `PUBLISH`, etc. I cannot get any hints on why they were slow.

I checked some documents about `SLOWLOG` but most of them just mentioned how to retrieve logs, but none of them provide information on how to solve.

Can anyone give me some suggestion on what I should do next to figure out why they were slow.

Comment: off-topic: Do you have a very large `SET`. If you do, the problem might lie on the `SMEMBERS` command, which blocks Redis for a long time, since it need retrieve all members of the `SET`. Instead, you should use `SSCAN` to retrieve members incrementally.

Comment: Mmm... I don't think 50+ elements in a `SET` is large. But `SSCAN` is one of alternative. Thanks for your hint. The problem is, I'm not sure if this was caused by the size of my `SET`s :(